# How to express solar generator capacity in MWh if I have MW?

Tags: solar-power, energy, electricity-generation

I have [this dataset](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.eia.gov%2Felectricity%2Fdata%2Feia860m%2Fxls%2Fjuly_generator2022.xlsx&wdOrigin=BROWSELINK) that is simply the nameplate capacity of different generators for a specific year in MW. I'm hoping to get a sum of all nameplate capacity for all solar generators for that year, but I would like to express it in MWh. Would that be possible, if we don't know in what time increments the data is logged? Any advice? I am generally confused about how to convert MW to MWh.

Comment: Does it help to think about km/h and km?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing power for energy.
I'll put it simply....
Energy is the capacity to perform work, as thermodynamic transfer or momentum.
Power is the rate at which energy is delivered in its transit in a given timeframe. (think of a faucet vs. a hose)

Energy is measured in Joules, Power in watts.
So One Joule per second is One watt
A Meagwatt is One million (Mega) watts based on its rate of delivery....A Megawatt-hour is one Megawatt over the course of one hour. A joule per second is one watt...
3.6 Gigajoules = 1 Megawatt-hour
1 Joule/sec = watt
1 watt per second is a joule
60x60 second = 1 hour x 1000000 watts = 3.6 Billion Joules
Best way to decipher energy/power delivery take your electric bill
Measured kilowatt-hours (kwh) and divide by 86400 seconds in a day.
There are 8,766 hours in a year...
take Megawatt-hours divided by 8,766 you get power per hour.

Example. A 50 MW generator running 24 hours generates 1,200 Megawatt-hours
prefixes for exponential orders of magnitude x1000

- Kilo: Thousand
- Mega: Million
- Giga: Billion
- Tera: Trillion
- Peta: Quadrillion

Answer (score 0):

Megawatt-hours is simply megawatts multiplied by hours, if the power of the generator stays constant at full power. To get megawatt-hours from megawatts, you need to know the duration. Usually in financial reporting, megawatt-hours means megawatt-hours per year actually, but it could mean megawatt-hours per quarter for example. And when comparing different months, megawatt-hours per month is a common unit.

An example: if you have 500 megawatts of generators, for a year it would be `24*365*500 = 4380000 MWh` which is so large number that you should switch to GWh: 4380 GWh.

It's also possible that the generators aren't running at full power all the time. This is taken into account by capacity factor. For example a peakload natural gas generator could have 15% capacity factor so in that case it would be 0.15 * 4380 GWh = 657 GWh.

For solar power, capacity factor varies based on average cloudiness and latitude. In sourthern Finland for example, averaged over one year, common capacity factors are 11-12%. But that doesn't tell the whole story as solar in Finland generates lots of energy during summer and practically no energy during winter.

So 500 MW of solar in Finland would be `24*365*500*0.115 = 503700 MWh`.

Bit older onshore wind power is 30% capacity factor when choosing a good site (a bad site can ruin production), today capacity factors are exceeding 35% for the newest turbines and good sites, and good offshore wind power site with newest turbines is expected to have 45-50% capacity factor.

Older non-pumped hydro has usually 50% capacity factor, although it could be really anything depending on how many turbines are installed. But older hydro was intended not for peaking power but rather load-following power and for that 50% capacity factor is ideal. Newer peakload hydro installations that are intended to produce power only during shortages should ideally have 15% capacity factor, i.e. with same storage pool size and same rainfall they would have more generators than older hydro installations.

Answer (score 0):

The link you've shared is from the U.S. Energy Information Agency's [monthly EIA-860 data](https://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/eia860M/), showing the [generator capacity](https://www.eia.gov/tools/glossary/index.php?id=G#gen_cap) in megawatts (MW). To use an analogy, this is like a report of the number of battery factories that are operating in a given month, and the highest quantity of batteries they could produce at any given moment.

Without knowing things like how much raw material those factories have, what shifts they operate, how many workers they have, etc, there's no way to know how many batteries they actually produce in a month just based on the capacity (though you might be able to make some assumptions and estimate).

Going back to the generator information, you need the [EIA-923 data](https://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/eia923/), which shows the actual energy production, in MWh, for each generator that is included in EIA-860. Net generation is provided in the sheet "Page 1 Generation and Fuel Data", in columns CB to CM. The acronyms and abbreviations used in the report are defined in the last sheet, "Page 7 File Layout."

Then you can match up the data, using the "Plant ID" column in the two reports. Here's a sample showing capacity from EIA-860, filtered to solar PV plants:

[image: EIA-860 screenshot]

And here's the corresponding data from EIA-923:

[image: EIA-923 screenshot]

(I'm not sure why there are more generators in EIA-860 than EIA-923 -- could be due to delays in reporting, plants that didn't produce anything that month, or some other factor).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a given output capacity of a generator, or multiple generators, in MW and you want to know how much energy does it produce over a given period in MWh then you can use the following formula

MWh = MW * Number of hours * Capacity Factor

Capacity Factor is the % of time the generator is producing at its named capacity.

So a 3 MW wind turbine over 24 hours, at a capacity factor of 30%,  will produce

3 * 24 * 0.30 = 21.6 MWh